# X : Y :: P : Q to find Q. whats the name of this method?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

This is a very simple relationship we often used but I don't remember the name of the method.
Thanks.

Comment: Ratio and proportion

Comment: your welcome.we are here to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Posting a CW answer to prevent autobumps.)

The name of the method is called "ratio and proportion".

(See comment by [iostream007](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392327/x-y-p-q-to-find-q-whats-the-name-of-this-method#comment839652_392327).)